# How to restore snapshot of docker image (for testing purpose, every test on this same docker image)

Tags: docker

I want to create an environment to run test on already prepared image. However docker stores a results from previously run tests, what can be illustrated by:

```
sudo docker run -t myname/test_base echo "test" >> /tmp/t; cat /tmp/t

test

sudo docker run -t myname/test_base echo "test" >> /tmp/t; cat /tmp/t

test
test
```

what I should do, if I simply want to restore initial state of image?

```
sudo docker run -t myname/test_base echo "test" >> /tmp/t; cat /tmp/t

test

<some magic>

sudo docker run -t myname/test_base echo "test" >> /tmp/t; cat /tmp/t

test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the docker image you are changing.  It's your host file system.  The bash redirection you're using '>>' puts the stdout of the docker run command into /tmp/t on your host file system.  To restore the state, you need to remove the file.

I think what you want is

```
docker run test_base bash -c 'echo test >> /tmp/t'
```

which will put the echo in the container file system, which will be lost when the process exits.